# How to Implement MVI in Android using just Java

Tags: android, design-patterns

Please does anyone have a link to a resource that helps in learning how to create an app using mvi design pattern but all code should be in Java and not Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Before you click! This is in `Kotlin` -> https://tech.olx.com/mvi-architecture-in-android-a-simple-livedata-based-approach-b4b23896fd32  But if you actually look at the code snippets there is not a single line that doesn't have an obvious `Java` counter part. There is not a single `Kotlin` exclusive item like `Flow`, `Scoping`, `Coroutine` anywhere.

You don't need to learn `Kotlin` to understand it, just read it.

The article explains `MVI` as a modified way to use a `MVVM`.

It has 2 *(`ViewState`/`ViewEffect`)* components that are observed by the view *(`Fragment`/`Activity`)*

It has 1 *(`ViewEvent`)* component that is used by the view to trigger changes in the observed components above.

`ViewState` :  It contains your data, like a `List`, like a  `boolean` that determines if something is `enabled`, etc...
When there is a change in any state data, like an update to the `List`, the `observer` receives everything, and updates everything.

`ViewEffect` : These are one off "effects" like starting an animation, making a `toast`. You will update this with new data when you not concerned about the state of the effect. Like I don't care if there is another `toast` on the screen, atm. Just make a new one with new information, and show it.

`ViewEvent` : This allows the `ViewModel` to receive events from the `view` and start the "update" process. If a button is clicked in the `view` all the `view` would do is send a `ViewEvent` to the `ViewModel` stating what has been clicked. Then the `ViewModel` updates the `ViewState`/`ViewEffect` based on the `ViewEvent` received, which then propagates to the view.

Comment: have you done this in plain java before, if so a link to the code will be highly appreciated. also is there any way to have an equivalent of data class and sealed class in java as that of kotlin

Comment: `data` = `POJO`  and `sealed` = `abstract`. Here is the rest of the conversions. https://medium.com/asos-techblog/kotlin-classes-in-java-world-365323843e6e

Comment: thanks, this is surely a life saver, time to play around with mvi in java. lol